# Issue in AJAX request in reactjs

Tags: ajax

I am trying to develop an application using reactjs as front end framework and laravel 5.6 as back end framework. I am trying to send AJAX request like below

```
import Auth from '../services/Auth';

var address_data = {
        name        :'foysal',                    
        address     :'foysal',
        telephone_no:'foysal',
        email       :'foysal',
}



fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/store/',address_data, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify()
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
    })
```

I am getting below errors

[image]

[image]

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify()` do you mean body: `JSON.stringify(address_data)` ?

Comment: I can see browser is initiating `GET` and not `POST`. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch on how to use `fetch` otherwise use simple `ajax` request

Comment: @AnatolyStrashkevich, sorry I could not understand.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati, Why it is sending `GET` request ? I think the issue is here ? What should I correct ? Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu Let me know if you are facing any issue once you try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your fetch request to initiate `POST` action verb like this

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/store/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(address_data)
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```